# How to check if a StringComparison is case sensitive?

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison

Given a `StringComparison` instance, how should I check if it is case sensitive?

Should I compare it to all currently known case sensitive values in the enum?

```
StringComparison sc = ...;
bool isCaseSensitive = false
    || sc == StringComparison.CurrentCulture
    || sc == StringComparison.InvariantCulture
    || sc == StringComparison.Ordinal;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for the enum form (`StringComparison`) that's fine. MS is incredibly unlikely to add another `StringComparison` value now, given that adding a value to an enum is effectively a breaking change.

For a `StringComparer`, it's rather harder :(

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes. `StringComparison` is an enum with 6 values, and there is no method to test them for their case sensitiveness.

You have to do it your own, and your method seems reasonable.

If you want a (nice | nasty) one-liner:

```
bool isCaseSensitive = (int)StringComparison.Ordinal % 2 == 1;
```

Comment: OMG that modulo hack is nasty.

Comment: @usr indeed. I don't recommend using it since it is totally hiding what is happening, but I think one liners are fun.

Comment: You could compute a cryptographic hash code of the comparison value. Also hash a salt value. Choose the salt so that the lowest bit of the hash is zero iff the comparison value is sensitive. This should happen for one in 64 salt values. That bit will then determine the value of `isCaseSensitive`. Now *that* would be a crazy way to write this condition.

Answer (score 1):

How about you actually use the provided enum to compare two strings?

```
bool isCaseSensitive = !("A".Equals("a", sc));
```

Comment: Uhhh more hacks. How nasty.

Comment: @usr Let's call it "naughty", as some people like that. I'm not going to admit anything,... but +1 for the idea.